# AngularJs ngTable loader

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ngtable

I am new to angularJS and ng table. Below is the code I am using to fetch data

```
$http.get('database/php_files/bus_chart.php').then(function(response) {
        $scope.records = response.data;

        $scope.tableRoute = new NgTableParams({
            page:1,
            count:10,
            sorting: { Source: "" } ,
            sorting: { Destination: "" },
            filter: { Source: "" } ,
            filter:{Destination:""}
            // filterOptions: { filterFn: fromToFilter },
        }, {
            dataset:$scope.records
        });




      });
```

My data is huge so need a loader while sorting and filtering, bcoz it takes time for the data to load. Please give me the solution.

Comment: may i know the records count ?

Comment: around 90,000 records

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'angular-loading-bar' in your project from below gitHub repository:

https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar

Comment: Initially loading bar is shown, but when sorting or filtering is done on ngtable , no loading bar is shown

Comment: It will only done when $http will be fire , and in your case your datatable is persisting all the data from  your table in single $http request and pagination is doing itself by datatable .

Answer (score -1):

A slim, site-wide progress-bar for AngularJS.

Check out here [ngProgress](http://victorbjelkholm.github.io/ngProgress/)